# Why might ros1_bridge stop forwarding lidar PointCloud2 messages?

Tags: ros2, lidar, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a large ROS network comprised of both ROS1 and ROS2 nodes. The nodes are bridged by the ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge.

Two of the ROS2 nodes publish VLP-32C lidar data as sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 onto two different lidar topics at ~10Hz. When the system starts up the ros1_bridge will correctly identify these topics and start forwarding these messages. However, after a few seconds at least one of the lidar streams will stop bridging and that lidar's data will no longer be available on the ROS1 network. It appears the ros1_bridge is still connected on both ends, but no lidar data is coming out. The ROS2 lidar data is still publishing and other messages are still being bridged.

I'm a bit at a loss for what might cause this. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to investigate.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS2 Foxy, ROS1 Noetic, and Cyclone DDS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397860/why-might-ros1_bridge-stop-forwarding-lidar-pointcloud2-messages?/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2022-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems this was caused by some known limitations in the way Cyclone DDS uses the kernal network.
I followed the suggestions here to resolve it
https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/DDS-tuning.html#cyclone-dds-tuning

Specifically the command

```
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=2147483647
```

---

Originally posted by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) with karma: 268 on 2022-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0